# Как использовать js c freemarker?

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, freemarker

Разбираюсь со spring mvc, в качестве шаблонизатора использую freemarker, появился такой вопрос: можно ли использовать js + freemarker? Когда пишу скрипт внутри ftl странички все отлично работает, но если выносить js код в отдельный файл, то не работает. Что я делаю не так? Вообще можно так делать? Или я пытаюсь сделать какое-то извращение?